# module object has no attribute windll from docker container

Tags: python, docker, ctypes, calling-convention

I am trying to run a python script from within a docker container on windows7.

The python scripts loads a DLL library and calls some functions in it according to the (__stdcall) convention. I am using ctypes in python to call functions. The script is working fine when i run it from python but it is just giving me an error while runned from a docker container.

Loading of the library

```
dll = ctypes.WinDLL("c:\\weCat3D\\weCat3D\\EthernetScanner\\EthernetScanner")
```

Error from docker container

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'windll'
```

what is the wrong thing I am doing?

Comment: A docker container is running on a Linux kernel, on Windows through a hypervisor. You will not have Windows only functionality available and you can't use Windows paths.

Comment: so its impossible to load a dll from within docker container?

Comment: Not impossible but it would need a compatibility layer like Wine. And frankly there is not much sense in simulating Windows in a hypervised and containered Linux hosted on Windows.

Comment: Did you try  `ctypes.CDLL`?

Comment: CristiFati The calling convention of the function in the library should be __stdcall. But I will try it. Is there any __stdcall convention in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Use all lowercase for `windll`. You can also check whether `ctypes` directory have `windll` or not by using `print (dir(ctypes))` on your console. 
I checked, `ctypes` contains `windll`. Check at your end. If not then upgrade your version.

Answer (score 0):

I am coming back to this issue to answer my question. I was trying to call a DLL library from within the docker container system which is containing a Linux image or Layer. That is why my calling convention for the DLL library (Windll) didn't work. I have got the same DLL library in .so (Linux version) and it is working now.